# I want to make the width of the zuck.js story item max 320px in resolutions on mobile

Tags: jquery, instagram, instagram-story

I have a problem. I'm trying to make the story width max 320px at high resolutions from mobile. So I want it to be the same as on Instagram. how can I do that

**zuck.js image**:
[image]

**The image I want it to be**: [image]

So as a result, only the zuck.js story in 1920px is spreading full. I want to get the view on Instagram

Answer (score 0):

have you solved it?
ugly fixd would be use an iframe the zuck part will be 100% width of your iframe
which you can manipulate in width how you want it

dont like this fix but you get the result what you are searching for